# How can I nest a SUMPRODUCT by month within COUNTIFS for three conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

How can I nest a SUMPRODUCT by month within COUNTIFS for three conditions. I need to count the number of items that are "Issued" in the status column that were issued within a specific year "2018" within February of that month.

```
=COUNTIFS(Table5[Application Year],'BP Dash Board'!B10,Table5[Status],"Issued",Table5[Application Date],SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(Table5[Application Date])='BP Dash Board'!D9)))
```

I need the sum product to be able to pull specific months in a date. Each of these arguments work as a stand alone but I need all three criterion matched before it counts them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can skip using COUNTIFS and just use SUMPRODUCT with the double-negative operator preceding each condition, with the condition itself wrapped in parentheses. The double-negative operator converts an array of TRUE/FALSE to an array of 1/0:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(Table5[Application Date])=$G$1),--(Table5[Application Year]=$G$3),--(Table5[Status]=$G$2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Drop the COUNTIFS(), SUMPRODUCT() can handle this on its own.

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Table5[Application date])='BP Dash Board'!D9)*(Table5[Application Year]='BP Dash Board'!B10)*(Table5[Status]="Issued"))`

Answer (score 0):

*What you are trying can be achieved by using `COUNTIFS` also. But since Dates to be matched with cell value, are part of the TABLE's range, therefore the formula needs to be adjusted for DATE check, instead of standard `COUNTIFS` syntax.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `F7`:

  ```
  =COUNTIFS(MyData[Date],">=02/01/2020",MyData[Date],"<=2/29/2020",MyData[Year],F$3,MyData[Status],F$4)
  ```

**N.B.**

*- Both COUNTIF & COUNIFS, doesn't works properly with the MONTH function to test Months.*

- If you use this one `{=MONTH(MyData[Date])=F2}` you get FALSE. Since `{=MONTH(MyData[Date])}` returns 1, for January.
- And if use these formula, returns ZERO.

  ```
  =COUNTIF(MyData[Date],(--(MONTH(MyData[Date])=F2)))
  ```

---

```
 =COUNTIFS(MyData[Date],$F$2,MyData[Year],$F$3,MyData[Status],$F$4)
```

---

*You may try this one also:*

```
=COUNT(IF(MONTH(MyData[Date])=F$2,0))+COUNT(IF(MyData[Year],F$3,0))+COUNT(IF(MyData[Status],F$4,0))
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of those options are pulling the correct data. I have 39 instances of February 2018 Issued. The first calculation says 0 the last calculation says 2...

Comment: @Saybier,, if possible share your Workbook on cloud and let me examine. The shown method is part of my Sheet,, as U can find the screen shot also. Write me what error or problem U are facing while using this method!!